# Spine - Is there an after_activated callback

Tags: spine.js

Is there an `after_activated` callback or a good way to implement it for the `Spine.Controller`?

I am using Spine Stack Manager, I found the `active` class is actually set when `active` function of the controller is completed/returned. So there's no interface for me to do something after the html content of the controller is set to show.

There's something I need to do like reseting the height of some elements, which require the corresponding elements to be showing.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution, implement `active` callback in the Stack Manager controller. It is called AFTER the controller is really set active, and I could get the activated controller instance.

Like the following:

```
class App.Main extends Spine.Stack
  @extend(Spine.Events)

  className: 'stack'

  controllers:
    normal: App.NormalMode
    cool: App.CoolMode
    crazy: App.CrazyMode

  default: 'normal'

  routes:
    '/normal': 'normal'
    '/cool': 'cool'
    '/crazy': 'crazy'


  constructor: () ->
    super

    @active (params) =>
      for controller in @manager.controllers
        controller.doSomething()
```